# When use widgets library in code::block with visual c++ 2010 compiler, occurs an error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, wxwidgets, codeblocks, visual-c++-2010

Firstly: I have `Code::Block v13.12`, `widgets v3.0.0` and `visual C++ 2010 compiler`;

When use `Code::Block` IDE to develop widgets applications, by using `visual c++ 2010 compiler` with it.
When compile any widgets application even hello world application, gives me an error `LINK||fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'wxmsw30u_dbgrid.lib'`.

I have searched for `wxmsw30u_dbgrid.lib` or `wxmsw30ud_dbgrid.lib` file in widgets lib folder, all lib files have been found except these lib files.

**What is the reason I have got this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dbgrid library doesn't exist in wxWidgets 3.0. I don't know where does the reference to it come from, but you should simply remove it from your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the corresponding DLL, you can [generate a lib from it](http://asawicki.info/news_1420_generating_lib_file_for_dll_library.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where can find it.

Comment: You'll find it where you (or CodeBlocks) have installed the wxWidgets development libraries. If it's still not there, download wxWidgets from the its website

Comment: I have searched in widgets and code::block folder, unfortunately the file not found.